# Case Sensitive PHP PDO login script

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I made a simple login system with PDO function like $user->login. I allows user to login with username in any case like USER, user. How do i make this script case sensitive without altering the essence of the code.

```
<?php

require_once('includes/config.php');

if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: topage.php'); } 

$message = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  if($user->login ($username,$password)){ 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: topage.php');
    exit;

  } else {
    $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
  }

}

?>
```

And also my password is salted using PDO command

```
$hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

and the Login function is

```
public function login($username,$password){

    $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

    if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not shown: What `login()` does. That's the important code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a framework. Please show the login function

Comment: Thanks @Akintunde. this is the code i use. no other functions used (I Guess) . after login it redirects into a form page for data entries.

Comment: There is a missing function called login.  You call the function when you perform the login function by.  $user->login(). Look for the file where the login function resides

Comment: thank you for @Ankintunde, Edited the question and added the function.

Comment: Sorry @tadman i wasn't that much clear to understand your answer. And thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use phpmyadmin to change the table column's collation to latin1_bin.
Do this to the column you want to make case sensitive